# Firestore Error: "Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined."

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing Infinite Scroll with Cloud Firestore and using the lastVisible as the document reference to know where to being the refreshing queries for another 5 users (limit is set to 5).

The issue is coming from "lastVisible" and is returning as undefined at the line marked with "ISSUE HERE." It doesn't seem to work with my state as it is now.

The error is:
**"Function Query.startAfter() requires a valid first argument, but it was undefined."** The error also happens if I use .startAt()

I also get the error:
**Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s** even though I'm using item.id for the keyExtractor.

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, FlatList, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/config';

// Imports: Components
import UserSelector from '../components/UserSelector';
import TitleLarge from '../components/TitleLarge';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Screen: Flat List (Users)
class FlatListUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      limit: 5,
      lastVisible: null,
      loading: false,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  // Component Will Mount
  componentWillMount = () => {
    // Firebase: Initialize
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: `${firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      authDomain: `${firebaseConfig.authDomain}`,
      databaseURL: `${firebaseConfig.databaseURL}`,
      projectId: `${firebaseConfig.projectId}`,
      storageBucket: `${firebaseConfig.storageBucket}`,
      messagingSenderId: `${firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId}`,
    });
  }

  // Component Did Mount
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.retrieveUsers();
  }

  // Retrieve Users
  retrieveUsers = async () => {
    try {
      // Set State: Loading
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Fetching Users')
      const initialQuery = await db.collection('users')
                        .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                        .orderBy('first_name')
                        .limit(this.state.limit);

      // Query Snapshot
      const querySnapshot = await initialQuery.get();

      // Document Data
      console.log('Document Data');
      const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
      console.log(documentData);

      // Last Visible Document
      let lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1];

      // Set State
      await this.setState({
        data: documentData,
        lastVisible: lastVisible,
        loading: false,
        refreshing: false,
      });

      console.log('Last Visible');
      console.log(typeof this.state.lastVisible)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.lastVisible))
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Retrieve More Users
  retrieveMore = async () => {
    try {
      const { lastVisible } = this.state;

      console.log('Retrieving more Users (Retrieve More)');
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      await console.log(`Last Visible (Retrieve More): ${this.state.lastVisible}`);

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Paginated Query starting (Retrieve More)');
      const paginatedQuery = await db.collection('licenses')
                        .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                        .orderBy('first_name')
                        .startAfter(lastVisible) // ISSUE HERE  ISSUE HERE  ISSUE HERE  ISSUE HERE
                        .limit(this.state.limit)

      // Query Snapshot
      const querySnapshot = await paginatedQuery.get();
      console.log(`Query Snapshot (Retrieve More): ${querySnapshot}`);

      // Document Data
      const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
      console.log(`Document Data (Retrieve More): ${documentData}`);

      // Last Visible Document (Used As Query Position)
      let lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1];
      console.log(`Last Visible New (Retrieve More): ${lastVisible}`);

      // Set State
      this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
          lastVisible: lastVisible,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false,
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Header
  renderHeader = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <TitleLarge title="Users" />
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Footer
  renderFooter = () => {
    try {
      // Check If Loading
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.activityIndicator}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
            <UserSelector
              key={(item, index) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              firstName={item.first_name}
              lastName={item.last_name}
              company={item.company}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => {
            item.id;
          }}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onEndReached={()=>{
            if (this.state.loading === false) {
             this.retrieveMore();
            }
          }}          
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: height,
    width: width,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  scrollView:{
    height: 'auto',
  },
  UserContainer: {
    width: width,
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#222222',
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: '#CED0CE',
  },
});

// Exports
export default FlatListUsers
```

Comment: I assume you mean `startAfter()` has an `undefined` argument, rather than `startAt()`?

Comment: Yes, it should be startAfter(). I was going back and forth testing to see if that would have changed anything.

Comment: You already have lots of console.log() calls, what do they say? Are they in the order you expect them to be?

Comment: Fetching Inspectors --> 

Document Snapshots --> 

Last Visible --> 

object --> 

null // Issue here from line 85? --> 
Document Data --> 
Retrieving more Inspectors (Retrieve More) --> 
Last Visible (Retrieve More): undefined // Issue here from line 111? --> 
Paginated Query starting (Retrieve More) -->